# libmysqlclient.so.18 not found for Centos 8

Tags: qt, centos8

I am trying to make connection in qt with mysql on Centos 8 using Qsqldatabase. But it gives error "Driver not loaded". So I am trying to find dependensies using command

ldd libqsqlmysql.so

Output:-
libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found

Kindly guid me to find libmysqlclient.so.18 for centos 8

Comment: I think you need to install `libqt5sql5` , in ubuntu  `sudo apt install libqt5sql5` is its command. and also in .pro file you should add `QT  += sql` and also see this site https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html

Comment: and also install `libmysqlclient-dev` ,

Comment: Thank you for answering my question....My problem solved by installing mysql-community-libs package